# How to change an elements in array of array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code I have:

```
l = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
n = []
for i in range(len(l)):
  n.append(l[i])
print(n)
```

I'm trying to select each element in the array to revers the number order only and putting it into a new array.

so I'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
[[3,'a'],[2,'b'],[1,'c']]
```

Comment: @blhsing's answer is fine as far as it goes. But since your question lacks enough context to know why you need that transformation it is impossible to know if that is a good answer. Especially in light of your solution which does nothing more than copy the `l` list to `n` with no transformation whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You can pair the reversed list with the list itself using `zip` in a list comprehension like this:

```
[[a, b] for (a, _), (_, b) in zip(reversed(l), l)]
```

This returns:

```
[[3, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [1, 'c']]
```

Or you can modify the list in-place by swapping items:

```
for i in range(len(l) // 2):
    l[i][0], l[len(l) - i - 1][0] = l[len(l) - i - 1][0], l[i][0]
```

`l` would become:

```
[[3, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [1, 'c']]
```